# select lines in file with same string pattern

Tags: linux, shell-script, string, pattern-matching

Let´s suppose I have the following `file.txt`:

```
asiub
sj
abq
b aia
ainp oo
test = 123d
sub ,.
aiba 87ab
test = 129szs bq
test = aqua
ayqvq 133s
```

I want to print only the lines of `file.txt` that contain the string `test =`.

desired `output.txt`:

```
test = 123d
test = 129szs bq
test = aqua
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep "test =" file.txt > output.txt`

For matching the string only at the beginning of a line, use

`grep "^test =" file.txt > output.txt`

Comment: good point @FelixJN , thanks for editing